# Statsmodels - TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types

Tags: python, datetime, statsmodels, arima

I a trying to run a block of code which assesses the Mean Squared error of different values for P,D & Q in a SARIMAX model. This exact block of code has worked just fine for me before and I haven't changed it anywhere so I can only assume the issue is the data but I have handled that in the same way as well so I can't figure out why it won't work?

```
def evaluate_sarima_model(data, arima_order, s_order): 
    split=int(len(data) * 0.8) 
    train, test = data[0:split], data[split:len(data)]
    past=[x for x in train]
    # make predictions
    predictions = list()
    for i in range(len(test)):
        model = sm.tsa.statespace.SARIMAX(past, order=arima_order, seasonal_order = s_order, enforce_stationarity=False, enforce_invertibility=False)
        model_fit = model.fit(disp=0)
        future = model_fit.forecast()[0]
        predictions.append(future)
        past.append(test[i])
    # calculate out of sample error
    error = mean_squared_error(test, predictions)
    return error
```

```
def evaluate_models(dataset, p_values, d_values, q_values, P_values, D_values, Q_values):
    best_score, best_cfg = float("inf"), None
    for p in p_values:
        for d in d_values:
            for q in q_values:
                for P in P_values:
                    for D in D_values:
                        for Q in Q_values:
                            order = (p,d,q)
                            s_order = (P, D, Q, 12)
                            try:
                                mse = evaluate_sarima_model(dataset, order, s_order)
                                if mse < best_score:
                                    best_score, best_cfg, seas = mse, order, s_order
                                print('SARIMA%s %s MSE=%.3f' % (order,seas, mse))
                            except:
                                continue
    return print('Best SARIMA%s %s MSE=%.3f' % (best_cfg, seas, best_score))
```

```
p_values = [1]
d_values = [1] 
q_values = [1] 
P_values = [x for x in range(0, 3)]
D_values = [x for x in range(0, 3)]
Q_values = [x for x in range(0, 3)]
```

I'm using the following dataset:

```
DatetimeIndex: 175 entries, 2005-12-01 to 2020-06-01
Freq: MS
Data columns (total 1 columns):
 #   Column    Non-Null Count  Dtype
---  ------    --------------  -----
 0   turnover  175 non-null    int32
dtypes: int32(1)
memory usage: 7.1 KB
```

And when I run it I get the following error:

```
evaluate_models(turnover_month, p_values, d_values, q_values, P_values, D_values, Q_values)

UnboundLocalError: local variable 'seas' referenced before assignment
```

Worth nothing that if I try to run a single model line using random values for P,D & Q I get the following so my assumption is that the issues is in the first block and how it is handling this dataset:

```
TypeError: ufunc 'isnan' not supported for the input types, and the inputs could not be safely coerced to any supported types according to the casting rule ''safe''
```

Comment: It looks like variable `seas` just isn't defined outside of the condition `if mse < best_score:`.  So if  condition is not met `seas` is not defined and the return statement attempts to use an undefined variable.

Comment: But how come the exact same block of code has worked absolutely fine elsewhere? I'm also not sure how I would rewrite the code to define it elsewhere?

Comment: Probably Luck. Is there anything preventing you from moving `seas = mse` above `if mse < best_score:`?

Comment: Just tried that and am still getting the same error unfortunately. So for reference the code block now says:

```try:
                                mse = evaluate_sarima_model(dataset, order, s_order)
                                seas = mse
                                if mse < best_score:
                                    best_score, best_cfg, seas, order, s_order
                                print('SARIMA%s %s MSE=%.3f' % (order,seas, mse))```

Comment: Take out the try and except. You probably have an unreported error that occurs prior to `seas` being defined.

Answer (score 0):

After going through every single line it became clear that it was the data that was the issue andthe SARIMA model is unable to handle DataFrames and instead needs Series. A simple .Squeeze() on the df was all I needed